# Least multiplier $M$ of $N$ such that $MN>X$

Tags: number-theory

Given integers $N$ and $X$, is there a well known algorithm to compute the least multiplier $M$ of $N$ such that $MN>X$?

For example, if $N=9$ and $X=13,000,000$, then $M=1444445$. (Since $1444444\times9=12,999,996$ and $1444445\times9=13,000,005$).

I'm looking for something much more efficient than brute force, because $M$  can be very large.

Also, is there an algorithm for the reverse; largest multiplier $M$ such that. $MN<X$?

Comment: Use [mathjax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Answer (score 0):

Let $M = \lfloor \frac{X}{N} \rfloor + 1$.

<sub>Note that the floor function should automatically be applied if you're doing integer division.</sub>

For your example, this would give 1444444 + 1 = 1444445.

For the largest $M$ such that $MN < X$, let $M = \lceil \frac{X}{N} \rceil - 1$, which is the same as $\lfloor \frac{X+N-1}{N} \rfloor - 1$.